# Avoid public constructor somehow C#

Tags: c#

I've just created some kind of generic repository, it seems to be working, my only problem is, is there any solution to avoid to use public constructor in classes what has to be instantiated to the repository?

My code is here:

```
public sealed class repository
{
    private static readonly object _lock = new object();

    private static readonly object _syncroot = new object();

    private static volatile repository _instance;

    private static readonly Dictionary<int, object> _dict
        = new Dictionary<int, object>();

    private repository()
    {
    }

    public static repository instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    if (_instance == null) _instance = new repository();
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public void allocate<Tc>(int id, object constructor_param) where Tc : Irepository<Tc>, new()
    {
        lock (_syncroot)
        {
            if (!_dict.ContainsKey(id))
            {
                var n = new Tc();
                _dict.Add(id, n.New(constructor_param));
            }
        }
    }

    public T get<T>(int id)
    {
        lock (_syncroot)
        {
            return (T) _dict[id];
        }
    }
}

public interface Irepository<out T>
{
    T New(object constructor_param);
}

public class RpSupportedClass : Irepository<RpSupportedClass>
{
    public object _constructor_param;

    private RpSupportedClass(object constructor_param)
    {
        _constructor_param = constructor_param;
    }

    public RpSupportedClass()
    {
    }

    public RpSupportedClass New(object constructor_param)
    {
        return new RpSupportedClass(constructor_param);
    }
}
```

So the problem is that I have to create a default public constructor:

```
    public RpSupportedClass()
    {
    }
```

...because of type parameter. I need type parameter by this way because I would like to use parameter in class instantiate sometimes.

Is there any way out?

Thank you!

Comment: Aside from anything else, are these really the names you're using? I'd *strongly* advise you to follow .NET naming conventions.

Comment: _"Is there any way out?"_. No.. the `new()` constraint means it is a requirement. If you want to hide your public constructor you need to re-think your design.